# Need to get the value of an input, is there a getElementById react equivalent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get the input from the user using an HTML form but I'm not sure what the react equivalent of getElementById is... how can I accomplish this without going into the DOM?

(speak in layman's terms please I'm new)

```
<input id="city" type="text" name="city" />
```

Comment: What's wrong with getElementById?

Comment: @cullanrocks unless I am mistaken it wont grab the value from reacts dom?

Comment: In React usually you add methods like input onChange or onSubmit form event, and then grab the value inside those functions.
You can read more in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react I usually set up event listeners on my inputs that handle state changes.

```js
handleChange = (inputValue) => {
  this.setState({inputValue})
}

<input 
  id="city" 
  type="text" 
  name="city" 
  onChange={ e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)} 
  value={this.state.inputValue}
/>
```